# Constant constructor in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

Can someone explain, what the advantages of constant constructors are? If I have a StatefulWidget

```
class X extends StatefulWidget {
  const X(this.a, this.b,...);
  A a;
  B b;
...
}
```

I do not understand why `const` is used. If I understand correctly, `const` means it is known at compile time, but what is it for? Usually the attributes `a`, `b`, etc. are not known at compile time, but at runtime, so what is the point for the `const` constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You current code cannot have a `const` constructor since some of the member variables in the class are not marked as `final`.

The purpose of `const` constructor is that if you create multiple instances of the same class with the same arguments on compile time (so all parameters can be determined by the compiler and is not runtime dependent) it will share the same instance in memory. This is only allowed since all member variables is `final`.

So the advantages is potential performance and memory improvements in specific cases (like some of the classes in `dart:convert`). But you must call the `const` constructor like `const MyClass();` for getting this `const` behavior. Else, a `const` can still be used like a normal constructor to get a normal instance of the class.

Personally, I will say that if you have a class with only `final` variables which are pointing to other `const` objects, there are really no reason for not creating a `const` constructor even if it is never going to be used. But you will often only be able to do this for simple data classes.

But it is also totally fine to not make a `const` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mark the member variables as `final` in my question. Does this mean that if I use a member variable `a`, that is not known at compile time, but loaded from a server for example, the const constructor has no effect? Something like `a = await loadFromServer(); X x = const X(a)` because `a` is not a constant?

Comment: You should not be able to do this since `a` is not a value which can be determined on compile time. There are rather strict rules for using the `const` keyword when calling a `const` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Constant constructor is a constructor that creates a constant object. A constant object is an object whose value cannot be changed. A constant constructor is declared using the keyword const.

In other words, Another aspect if the objects produced by the class are intended to remain unchanged throughout their lifetime, including the values of their variables, you have the option to designate them as compile-time constants.

By marking these objects as compile-time constants, you ensure that their values are set during compilation and remain constant during runtime. This can provide benefits such as improved performance and reduced memory consumption, especially in scenarios where the same values are repeatedly used.

To achieve this, you can employ techniques like utilizing the final keyword for variables and ensuring that no mutable operations are performed on the objects after their initialization.